# How to override fit() and predict() in a Keras model

Tags: keras, sequential, label-encoding

I've created a subclass of the `keras.models.Sequential` class, so that to override the `fit()` and `predict()` functions.

My goal is to 'hide' the a `sklearn` `LabelEncoder`. This way I can directly call `fit()` and `predict()` with a `y` array made up of arbitrary labels, without the requirement of them being integers in the range [0, 1, ..., `num_classes` - 1].

Implementation example:

```py
import numpy as np

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

class SuperSequential(Sequential):

  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
    self.encoder = LabelEncoder()

  def fit(self, X: np.ndarray, y: np.ndarray, **kwargs) -> Sequential:
    y_enc = self.encoder.fit_transform(y)
    y_enc = to_categorical(y_enc, len(np.unique(y_enc)))

    return super().fit(X, y_enc)

  def predict(self, X: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    y_pred = super().predict(X)
    y_pred = np.argmax(y_pred , axis=1)

    return self.label_encoder.inverse_transform(y_pred)
```

Unfortunately, this isn't very convenient for my use case. I'd like to save a trained model using `keras.models.save_model()` and then load everything via `keras.models.load_model()`. However, the loaded model is always of the base `Sequential` class, which does not include the overridden `fit()` and `predict()`.

**UPDATE:** If I load the model passing the appropriate `custom_objects` field (as shown below), the loaded object does have the expected type (`SuperSequential`), but the `LabelEncoder` isn't 'fitted'.

```py
keras.models.load_model("model_path", custom_objects={"SuperSequential": SuperSequential})
```

I've also found that Keras allows the use of pre-processing layers such as `keras.layers.IntegerLookup`, which seems to do what I want, but it isn't clear to me how to use it as part of a `Sequential` model for label encoding.

My questions are:

1. How can I save and load a subclass of `Sequential`, if at all possible?
2. How could I achieve the same goal as with the sub-class but with a Keras pre-processing label such as `keras.layers.IntegerLookup`?
3. The lack of supporting references for what I'm trying to do leads me to think that this doesn't make sense. Is there a better method to achieve my goals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer my own question, as it may help someone in the future.

The 'overriding' approach was not the correct one.

The label encoding and decoding steps are **pre- and post-processing steps**. As such, they should not be 'shoehorned' in the `fit()` and `predict()` methods, but rather be added as additional layers in the `Sequential` model.

This keeps concerns separated and doesn't hide the pre- and post-processing steps, as they'll be visible when one inspects a loaded model via `tf.keras.Model.summary()`, for example.

I ended following a two step approach:

1. **Training:** I create a label encoder object that takes care of encoding the original labels into a 'one-hot-encoded' 2D array. I've used a `keras.layers.IntegerLookup` object to accomplish this. I then pass the original labels to this label encoder, and simply `fit()` the model with the encoded labels.
2. **Inference:** After training the model, I create an 'inference' version of the model (perhaps a better term should be 'pipeline' instead of 'model'), by adding two **post-processing** layers to it: (a) a custom `argmax` layer that extracts the encoded labels with highest probability; and (b) a label decoding layer (also based a `keras.layers.IntegerLookup` object) that essentially does the opposite of the pre-processing object I've used in step 1.

After step 2, I can save the 'inference' version of the model using `keras.models.save_model()`, which includes the post-processing layers. When `load()` is called, all I have to do is call `predict()`, which directly provides me an array with the predicted class labels, in their original format.

In order to implement the `argmax` layer, I had to implement a custom `Keras` layer, as shown in the example at the bottom.

For reference, here's a concrete example:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras import layers


class ArgMax(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    """
    Custom Keras layer that extracts the labels from 
    an array of probabilities per label.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        super(ArgMax, self).__init__()

    def call(self, inputs):
        return tf.math.argmax(inputs, axis=1)


def load_dataset(discard:list=[]):
    """
    Loads mnist dataset, filters out unwanted labels and re-shapes arrays.
    """
    (X_tr, y_tr), (X_val, y_val) = mnist.load_data()

    X_tr = X_tr[~np.isin(y_tr, discard),:]
    y_tr = y_tr[~np.isin(y_tr, discard)]

    X_val = X_val[~np.isin(y_val, discard),:]
    y_val = y_val[~np.isin(y_val, discard)]

    NUM_ROWS = X_tr.shape[1]
    NUM_COLS = X_tr.shape[2]

    X_tr = X_tr.reshape((X_tr.shape[0], NUM_ROWS * NUM_COLS))
    X_val = X_val.reshape((X_val.shape[0], NUM_ROWS * NUM_COLS))

    X_tr = X_tr.astype('float32') / 255
    X_val = X_val.astype('float32') / 255

    return (X_tr, y_tr), (X_val, y_val)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # load dataset : discard some of the labels 
    # to test correct operation of pre- and post-processing layers
    (X_tr, y_tr), (X_val, y_val) = load_dataset(discard=[1, 3, 5])

    # label pre-processing
    label_preprocessing = layers.IntegerLookup(
        output_mode="one_hot", 
        num_oov_indices=0
    )
    label_preprocessing.adapt(y_tr)
    print(f"vocabulary : {label_preprocessing.get_vocabulary()}")
    print(f"vocabulary size : {len(label_preprocessing.get_vocabulary())}")

    # label post-processing 
    label_postprocessing = layers.IntegerLookup(
        num_oov_indices=0,
        invert=True
    )
    label_postprocessing.adapt(y_tr)
    print(f"vocabulary : {label_postprocessing.get_vocabulary()}")
    print(f"vocabulary size : {len(label_postprocessing.get_vocabulary())}")

    # create model using Sequential API
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu', input_shape=(X_tr.shape[1],)))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(len(np.unique(y_tr)), activation='softmax'))

    model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

    # fit the model using the pre-processed labels
    model.fit(X_tr, label_preprocessing(y_tr),
          batch_size=128,
          epochs=10,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=(X_val, label_preprocessing(y_val)))

    # create model for inference, i.e., with 2 post-processing layers:
    #   - add a layer that does argmax() operation
    #   - add a layer to invert the integer labels
    model.add(ArgMax())
    model.add(label_postprocessing)

    # save the model
    model.save('inference_model')

    # load the model
    loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('inference_model')

    # compare the first 20 predictions of the loaded model to the ground truth
    print(loaded_model.predict(X_val[:20]))
    print(y_val[:20])
```